# PrestaShop 1.7 слайдер во всю ширину экнрана

Tags: слайдер, prestashop

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая проблема: никак не могу растянуть стандартный слайдер на всю ширину экрана, ползую в файле theme.css по .carousel. Нашел 
в

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
}
```

можно добавить width и height и установить размер в пикселях, он становится меньше или больше, но ведь хочется, чтобы все было адаптивно и под разные разммеры. Быть может кто-то сталкивался с таким вопросом. Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто расположите модуль слайдера в этот хук

Comment: В 1.7 Версии нет такого `DisplayNavFullWidth`.
Или это сторонняя штука?